# CSS creating a CSS3 transparent overlay in the style of a graident

Tags: css, overlay, transparency

I have the image below and I am wanting to create the white overlay using CSS3 but I am not sure how or the best way to do it.  Would RGBA be best?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the image-background is white, you could set the opacity of the image itself to a value less than 1.

This way, you don't have to make an overlay.

If the background is not white, `rgba()` would be the easiest way to do it and there is nothing that speaks against it.

You could also use `opacty: 0.5;` but there is nearly no difference.

Comment: Thanks,  How would I make it a maximum width by using a span with the opacity?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a `width`, and a `min-width`, but nothing like a `max-width`. If you want the image to have a maximum-width, you have to put it inside a div/span, and declare `width = ..; opacity = 0.5;`.